# Is possible to find the location from address?

Tags: android, android-location

I am not sure if this can be done in android. I have a direction of a place (example: Langestraat 44 2018 Antwerpen) and with that I want to know the latitude and longitude. Am I asking too much or it can be made?

Comment: that is calling Geocoding, if you google `Android geocode` you'll find examples, tutos etc, about it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html

Comment: No I only have the direction of the place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes  You can use the following  Code to get Latitude and Longitude from the Address

```
 List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(  
                locationName, 5);  
        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {  
            int lat = (int) (addressList.get(0).getLatitude() * 1000000);  
            int lng = (int) (addressList.get(0).getLongitude() * 1000000);  
            GeoPoint pt = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);  
            mapView.getController().setZoom(15);  
            mapView.getController().setCenter(pt);  
        }
```